Android: set imageView by name string of file in drawable
I note this was asked a lot over 10 years ago, and the various answers do not work today.
Basically I have a various images saved in my Drawable assets.
I also have an online database with the names of these images. This database serves iOS and Android apps.
I'm using a recycle view and want to set an imageView based on the string value (name of image) I download from the database. Basically I have a list of titles and associated images.
In iOS I easily set the images using the image name linking to the bundle images.
I can not find a similar easy method in android:
I have kept reading I need to get the resID, and use this to set the image. But I'm unable to do the as the getResorce is deprecated.
I don't understand why I can't just provide a path to the image using the image name like I would in iOS?
I don't have any specific code to show, thus far I have a image name string (of the relevant image) and I want to set it to my ViewHolder: holder.imageSection
Any help please...some aspects of Android I have overly complex / difficult to achieve
UPDATE:
Using in my activity which populates array:
int IDRes = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());

getResource is scored out
Then using this in my adapter for recycler:
holder.imageSection.setImageResource(IDRes);

Nothing happens, no images. If I hard code one specific drawable, that shows.

"But I'm unable to do the as the getResorce is deprecated." -- it is unclear what you are referring to here. getIdentifier() is how you look up a resource ID by name. "I don't understand why I can't just provide a path to the image using the image name" -- it is not a file on the device. It is an entry in an APK file.

Please see update

"getResource is scored out" -- there is no getResource() there. getResources() is not deprecated anywhere that I can find. What specific class are you getting getResources() from? Also, you should examine IDRes to see what you are getting back, and make sure that imageName does not have the file extension (e.g., use avatar, not avatar.png).

Apologies, getIdentifier is scored out on Android studio, has warning stating: "Use of this function is discouraged....". I'm getting '0' for each image. not using extensions

The use is discouraged for the performance implications mentioned in some of the duplicates. You might check what getPackageName() is returning and confirm that it matches what you need for your module. Basically, you need that value to be the basis of what your R class import would be for R.drawable.avatar. Another option, if you do not have a long list of drawables, is to build yourself a Map<String, Integer> where you map your names to the R.drawable constants, then use that map to look up identifiers at runtime. This will be faster to run, but a pain to write.

Thanks again. the getPackageName() appears correct. I cannot see why it's returning 0. The image name doesn't have extension. Everything feels like it should work. About to give up

Well, fixed it. The code above does work. The issue was I forgot android converts all drawable (?resource) filenames to lower case. All my images are titleImage etc (capital I). Android converts them all to lower case, thus when searching for the drawable it always came up blank. Created a simply workaround and working. I really do struggle moving from iOS (which I know well) to Android due to little issues like this. Thanks again to CommonsWare for help and confirming the code should work and to check the path
